# Windows SED command - simple search and replace without regex

Tags: windows, c#-4.0, sed, gnu

How should I use 'sed' command to find and replace the given word/words/sentence without considering any of them as the special character?

In other words hot to treat find and replace parameters as the plain text.

In following example I want to replace 'sagar' with '+sagar' then I have to give following command

```
sed "s/sagar/\\+sagar@g"
```

I know that \ should be escaped with another \ ,but I can't do this manipulation.
As there are so many special characters and theie combinations.

I am going to take find and replace parameters as input from user screen.
I want to execute the sed from c# code.

Simply, I do not want regular expression of sed to use. I want my command text to be treated as plain text?

Is this possible? 
If so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there may be `sed` versions that have an option like `--noregex_matching`, most of them don't have that option. Because you're getting the search and replace input by prompting a user, you're best bet is to scan the user input strings for reg-exp special characters and escape them as appropriate.

Also, will your users expect for example, their all caps search input to correctly match and replace a lower or mixed case string? In that case, recall that you could rewrite their target string as `[Ss][Aa][Gg][Aa][Rr]`, and replace with `+Sagar`.

Note that there are far fewer regex characters used on the replacement side, with '&' meaning "complete string that was matched", and then the numbered replacment groups, like `\1,\2,...`. Given users that have no knowledge or expectation that they can use such characters, the likelyhood of them using is `\1` in their required substitution is pretty low. More likely they may have a valid use for `&`, so you'll have to scan (at least) for that and replace with `\&`. In a basic sed, that's about it. (There may be others in the latest gnu seds, or some of the `sed`s that have the genesis as PC tools).

For a replacement string, you shouldn't have  to escape the `+` char at all. Probably yes for `\`. Again, you can scan your user's "naive" input, and add escape chars as need.

Finally if you're doing this for a "package" that will be distributed, and you'll be relying on the users' version of `sed`, beware that there are many versions of sed floating around, some that have their roots in Unix/Linux, and others, particularly of `super-sed`, that (I'm pretty sure) got started as PC-standalones and has a very different feature set.

IHTH.